# Microsoft test result in Excel format

Tags: trx

Is there any tool exist that transfroms trx file into Excel format?

I am looking for something that will automate unit test result publishing at the time of test suite execution (without requiring microsoft team server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://trx2html.codeplex.com/ which provides an easy way to convert an rtx file into an html document.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the information about the test name and whether passed or failed, you could copy the columns from Test Results UI (in Visual Studio) and paste on excel.

Answer (score -2):

I created a tool for this propose, the trx file will be converted to Excel 2010 format with useful information.
Pls try: https://youtu.be/G7VASkhim7I

#### Instructions

1. Download the Trx2Excel application from [here](https://tusfiles.net/tqrdy3nvvmtp) and run the application.
2. Select the option: *Get data from one file or from a folder*.
3. Select the result file (for single file option) or result folder (for multiple files option).
4. Select the location and the saved file (the output file).
5. Click the *Convert* button.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This solution is throwing an exception when I try to convert the file